# Importance of a Random Variable using Entropy or other method

Tags: random, entropy, information-theory, cross-entropy

I have a two-dimensional random vector **x** = [*x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>]<sup>T</sup> with a known joint probability density function (PDF). The PDF is non-Gaussian and the two entries of the random vector are statistically *dependent*. I need to show that for example *x*<sub>1</sub> is *more important* than *x*<sub>2</sub>, in terms of the amount of *information* that it carries. Is there a classical solution for this problem? Can I show that for example n% of the *total information* carried by **x** is in *x*<sub>1</sub> and 100-n% is carried by *x*<sub>2</sub>?

I assume that the standard way of measuring the amount of *information* is by calculating the Entropy. Any clues?